# How to type exact sequences.

Tags: support, mathjax, images

I want to post a question related to a proposition on exact sequences from the book by Atiyah. But I don't know how to type an exact sequence here in MathJax. I have seen few worked out complete examples, but from those examples it was highly difficult for me to point out which symbols stands for what. Any comprehensible help from any end is welcome.

Comment: By "I have seen few worked out complete examples" you mean that you have seen some examples of posts at this site which contained exact sequences? Maybe if you link to those posts and explain what was unclear to you, some users will be give a more detailed explanation or direct you to some documentation or tutorials.

Comment: BTW [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram/12372#12372) suggests that if you know xypic, you can use presheaf and then paste the commutative diagram into your post as an image.

Comment: And I guess that more a appropriate tag for your question would be ([meta-tag:support]). I do not see any ([meta-tag:feature-request]) in your question. Neither it is clear what the ([meta-tag:bug]) is supposed to be.